# Django collectstatic does not work as expected

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

In my Django app, it only has access to part of the static files when Debug = False, any idea why?

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app/static'),
)
```

After I do collect static I can see the files but for same reason it returns 404

Comment: Django does not serve static files in production mode. It is expected that configure a separate webserver in production.

Comment: @KlausD. It's working for part of my static files because a few CSS files are being founded but not for the rest of them

Comment: You didn't mention if your are (still) using the devserver or a separate webserver as suggested by @KlausD. and of course the Django docs.